# Camel Multicast Subroutes out of order

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic, multicast

I have a scenario where I get as input Message A. Message A must then be split into 3 different types of message, and forwarded to other routes. It is important that the messages arrive in a precise order, Ie. A-1 must be sent before A-2, which must be sent before A-3.

To do this I have done the following (outline):

```
from("activemq:queue:somequeue-local")
  .multicast().to("direct:a1","direct:a2","direct:a3");

from("direct:a1)
  //split incoming message and prepare output document for A-1
  .to("activemq:queue:otherqueue")

.from("direct:a2)
  //split incoming message and prepare output document for A-2
  .to("activemq:queue:otherqueue")

.from("direct:a3)
  //split incoming message and prepare output document for A-3
  .to("activemq:queue:otherqueue")
```

And in another context, responsible for sending out the info to the external system, I have

```
.from("activemq:queue:otherqueue?maxMessagesPerTask=1&concurrentConsumers=1&maxConcurrentConsumers=1")
      // do different stuff based on which type we are called with then end with
     .beanref("somebean","writeToFileAndCallImportbat");
```

Now, my problem is, that when I get to the receiver, I get the messages in random order. Sometimes A-1,A-3,A-2, sometimes right, A-1,A-2,A-3.

I have tried adding JMSXGroupID and JMSXGroupSeq to the messages, but without any luck.

I have also tried skipping the MQ part entirely, and use direct-vm: to call the shared receiver, but then it looks like I have three simultanious invocations of the receiver at once, and still in random execution order.

I was under the impression that multicast would run sequential, unless otherwise prompted to?

Is there something fundamentally wrong with the approach taken?

I am using Camel version 2.12.

Or, said more plainly:

- I would like a route that creates three different output messages, and executes a batch file on them, in order. How do I go about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the [Splitter pattern](http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html), have you checked to see if the **streaming** property is set to false.

> If enabled then Camel will split in a streaming fashion, which means it will split the input message in chunks. This reduces the memory overhead. For example if you split big messages its recommended to enable streaming. If streaming is enabled then the sub-message replies will be aggregated out-of-order, eg in the order they come back. If disabled, Camel will process sub-message replies in the same order as they where splitted.

Comment: You were totally right. The problem was in how I was handling splitting, although not exactly for the reasons you state. But given my example didn't show the details of that, there was no way to see.

Answer (score 0):

So, it turned out to not be a problem with multicast after all.

Rather, in each of my sub-routes, I did this:

```
.split(..stax(SpecialClass)).streaming()
.beanRef("transformationBean","somefunction")
.aggregate(constant("1"), new MyAggregator())
.completionTimeout(5000)
.completionSize(1000)
.to(writeToFileAndRunBat)
```

Which, I assumed meant "Process all elements in the split, and if you aren't finished in 5 seconds or after 1000 elements, break out".

I changed it to

```
.split(..stax(SpecialClass), , new MyAggregator()).streaming()
.beanRef("transformationBean","somefunction")
.end()
.to(writeToFileAndRunBat)
```

Coming to think of it, it makes perfect sense, as the first version couldn't really know when we were done, while the last (I assume) just iterate over all elements in the split and calls the Aggregator for each.

Also, I had to .end() in the first version. So I guess the whole thing was just acting random.